# Haxe and Socket.IO for web & mobile

Tags: socket.io, haxe

We have a game that is written with Adobe Flash and the server side is NodeJS and they communicate with socket.io.

We consider moving to Haxe, the problem is that when I try to google for Haxe and socket.io, I only find indications for it to operate together using haxe-js-kit.

Does anyone have any experience with Haxe and Socket.IO?

How is the performance of using haxe-js-kit for socket.io support?

Can I use haxe-js-kit both on browser and mobile and it will work properly?

Any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Following twitter there are a fresh [socket.io externs](https://github.com/gogoprog/hxsocketio/)

For experience/recommendations go to [haxe group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haxelang)

Comment: hxsocketio has only javascript target. it will not work on mobile.

Comment: [socket.io-openfl-client](https://github.com/dimanux/socket.io-openfl-client) will be better?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't have secured https connection support yet

Answer (score 1):

There are probably no pure Haxe port of Socket.io. If you intent on using it for OpenFL/Kha/etc. you'll want to port a Flash library to Haxe.